# How to use the URL ignoring controller's default behavior in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have a CI codebase in my localhost whose URL is `http://localhost/mydomain/site/`

here "site" is a folder **NOT** controller

I have DB table data field where locations of certain areas are stored.

Ideally when the above URL is hit, the default "home" controller is called.

But I Want if user hit the URL as `http://localhost/mydomain/site/southtown/` where "southtown" is the locatily name, user can see all the southtown associated data pn the view page.

**Note:** the data comes on the basis of location(here southtown) from database.

Also there will be URLS as

localhost/mydomain/site/southtown/aboutus

localhost/mydomain/site/southtown/inspiration

localhost/mydomain/site/southtown/services

These will be the respective pages as per locations specified in URL all data coming from DB

Answer (score 2):

try using routes, like

```
$route["home"] = "home";
$route["home/(:any)"] = "home/index/$1";
```

and in your `home` controller, do:

```
public function index($location = "") {
   //get $location and check against db
}
```

So, when use hits url `http://localhost/mydomain/site/southtown/`, your `$location` will have value "southtown" for it.

Comment: @Sudhir site is folder, not a controller

Comment: @OMTheEternity see the update, since your default controller that gets called is home, you could use routes for your 'home' controller

Comment: @Sudhir I have just Update question with the future implmentations with this URL...